Uncaught TypeError: Function has non-object prototype 'undefined' in instanceof check
I am struggling with this error that happens only when "vite build" is ejecuted (npm run build), but it does not happen when "npm run dev" in my local.
These is all I did at the moment:

I make sure that both node versions are the same in local and prod: 16.17.0
and npm 8.15.0
I removed the node_modules and install again
I run a build again "npm run build" in production
I remove all the caches from laravel with artisan as always

But it does not matter what I do, I always see the same error message in the chrome console, and the site (Laravel+ Vue3+ Inertia + vite) does not load.
app-CQaiJHst.js:9445 Uncaught TypeError: Function has non-object prototype 'undefined' in instanceof check
    at [Symbol.hasInstance] (<anonymous>)
    at Function.a3 (app-CQaiJHst.js:9445:16)
    at app-CQaiJHst.js:9788:21

This is the vite.config.js file (I've tried many different configuration with the same result)
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
              
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        commonjs(),

        
    ],

    resolve:{
        alias: {
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist'),

        }
    },
    build: {
        minify: false,
        commonjsOptions: {
            requireReturnsDefault: 'auto',
        },
    },
});


Any clue? Thanks

Note: This last part from the vite config file does not matter if is there or not (I get the same error) :
 build: {
      minify: false,
      commonjsOptions: {
    requireReturnsDefault: 'auto',
         },
     },

This is the piece of code (from the JS build) that generates the error (only in production)
      if (this instanceof a3) {
        return Reflect.construct(f2, arguments, this.constructor);
      }

Here is the full file generated by the "npm run dev"
https://justpaste.it/98pyw

Fixed!! I even don't know how now it is working, but after try thousands of things, this vite configuration solves the issue:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
// import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import path from 'path';
// import vitePluginRequire from 'vite-plugin-require';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
      
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                 
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        })
       
    ],

    resolve:{
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js'),
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist'),

        }
    },
    build: {
        outDir: 'public/build',
        commonjsOptions: {
            requireReturnsDefault: 'auto',
            transformMixedEsModules: true
        },
        minify: false

    }
});

I think the solution was to add this " transformMixedEsModules: true".
